# Sort by selection in C#

Tags: c#

I am a complete beginner in programming. Trying to make sorting a choice. Everything seems to be ok. Only there is one caveat. Only numbers up to 24 index are filled in the new array. I can’t understand what the problem is.

```
  int[] Fillin(int[] mass)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < mass.Length; i++)
        {
            mass[i] = r.Next(1, 101);
        }
        return mass;
    }
    int SearchSmall(int[] mass)
    {
        int smallest = mass[0];
        int small_index = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < mass.Length; i++)
        {
            if (mass[i] < smallest)
            {
                smallest = mass[i];
                small_index = i;
            }
        }
        return small_index;
    }
    int[] Remove(int[] massiv,int remind)
    {
        List<int> tmp = new List<int>(massiv);
        tmp.RemoveAt(remind);
        massiv = tmp.ToArray();
        return massiv;
    }
    public int[] SortMass(int[] mass)
    {
        mass = Fillin(mass);
        Print(mass);
        Console.WriteLine("________________________________");
        int[] newmass = new int[mass.Length];
        int small;
        for(int i = 0; i < mass.Length; i++)
        {
            small = SearchSmall(mass);
            newmass[i] = mass[small];
            mass = Remove(mass, small);
        }
        return newmass;
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like a good learning opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Using a debugger you can place a breakpoint in your code to pause the execution and step through the code line by line as it executes, observing the exact runtime behavior and changing values of your variables.  When you do this, which operation in your code first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used at the time?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: This is the most inefficient sorting I have ever seen ... About your problem... You are iterating through mass, which is getting smaller every iteration. You never reach the end of newmass. I think you want to iterate through newmass. As in newmass.Length instead of mass.Length

Comment: your sorting is totally out of whack. Look into simple bubbling technique

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue is that when you remove an element in the `Remove`  function, the main loop in `for (int i = 0; i < mass.Length; i++)` will not check all elements o the initial array. A simple (and ugly) way to fix that would be not to remove the elements but to assign a very high value

```
public static int[] Remove(int[] massiv, int remind)
{
            massiv[remind] = 999999;
            return massiv;
}
```

Or as Legacy suggested simply modify the mass.length for newmass.lengh in the main loop.

As some others have mentioned this is not the best way to order an array, but it is an interesting exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything is working. The problem was precisely that I indicated mass.Lenght, not newmass.Lenght.